# Flutter TextSelection.collapsed: The named parameter 'offset' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, textselection

I am getting an error using the Flutter's `TextSelection.collapsed`:

> The named parameter 'offset' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'offset'.

[image]

However, the Flutter API [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextSelection/TextSelection.collapsed.html) lists `offset` as a required `int` parameter. What's the solution to this?

Comment: If you updated to Flutter 1.22.0, do `flutter pub get` and restart IDE

Comment: That indeed was the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just reload your IDE:on VSCODE for example when you switch to flutter version 1.22.6 a notification appears to restart the IDE